# Amazon AWS server side encryption in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my app, I'm uploading the images attached by the user to S3 bucket in which server side encryption is used.

We have used the following code in Android to achieve this and it WORKED.

```
try
{
    SSECustomerKey sseCustomerKey = new SSECustomerKey(BuildConfig.S3_AES_ENCRYPT_KEY);
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(mContext, AWSCognitoPoolId, Regions.fromName(Regions.US_EAST_1.getName()));
    AmazonS3Client sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(sCredProvider);
    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(BuildConfig.S3_BUCKET_NAME, file.getName(), file).withSSECustomerKey(sseCustomerKey);
    sS3Client.putObject(putRequest);
    sS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(Regions.US_EAST_1.getName())));
}
```

But in iOS, it is not working. Please find the following iOS code.

```
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest?.bucket = bucketName
uploadRequest?.body = fileURL
uploadRequest?.key = imageName[i]
uploadRequest?.serverSideEncryption = .AES256
uploadRequest?.sseCustomerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/jpeg"

transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith(block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
    if let error = task.error as NSError? {
        if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain as String {
            if let errorCode = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
                switch (errorCode) {
                case .cancelled, .paused:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
            }
        } else {
            print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
        }
    }
    return nil
})
```

I get the following error in iOS

> upload() failed: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0
>   "(null)" UserInfo={RequestId=C7302D0F4DD27397,
>   HostId=Dm3itGpwZNcpPq28qfFkKDlB2VFbOzIYn01T270QzzVXJ9lmZWU2bX7oPXyXrG5A86OpfTrXSHw=,
>   Message=Server Side Encryption with Customer provided key is
>   incompatible with the encryption method specified,
>   ArgumentValue=AES256, Code=InvalidArgument,
>   ArgumentName=x-amz-server-side-encryption}]

Please show me some light on this

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use TransferUtility instead of TransferManager. The TransferManager is on a deprecation path and doesn't have all the features that the TransferUtility has. Here is a code snippet showing how you can upload a file with server side encryption.

```
 let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
 let uploadExpression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
 uploadExpression.setValue("AES256", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-server-side-encryption")

 uploadExpression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
     print("Upload progress: ", progress.fractionCompleted)
 }

 let uploadCompletionHandler = { (task: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
              //Error completing transfer. Handle Error
        }
        else {
               //Successfully uploaded.
               ......
               return nil
         }
    }

    transferUtility.uploadData(
        data,
        bucket: "bucket",
        key: "key",
        contentType: "contenttype",
        expression: uploadExpression,
        completionHandler: uploadCompletionHandler
        ).continueWith (block: { (task) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
                //Error initiating transfer. Handle error
            }

            return nil
        })

}
```

Here is a link to more information on how to use TransferUtility - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-transfer-files-with-transfer-utility.html

Comment: This code worked and file has been uploaded to the S3 bucket. But how to pass the SSE_CUSTOMER_KEY as done in the Android code?

Comment: You can set it in the uploadExpression: `uploadExpression.setValue(key, forRequestHeader: "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key")`

Comment: Only this single key won't work now, Look at the aws documentation they mentioned the constraints there are 2 more keys which are necessary to send with this key, Please see my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

Now it's been years but still this answer would help someone and save hours of searching which i have gone through, TransferManager is deprecated so now we are using transferUtility s3 to upload files, But if we want to encrypt the files we have to send 3 keys in the header

```
expression.setValue("AES256", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm")
expression.setValue(base64String, forRequestHeader: "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key")
expression.setValue(md5String, forRequestHeader: "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5")
```

These 3 keys are necessary otherwise the transfer utility won't upload the file and give u an error, x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm this key is use to tell which encryption algorithm u want to use, For the other 2 keys we have to generate them, Sample code is this to generate base64String and md5, There are many ways to generate the key you can look at the CryptoSwift docs, I have used Salt which makes it more secure then brute force attacks

```
let input: Array<UInt8> = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    let password: [UInt8] = Array("s33krit".utf8)
    let salt: [UInt8] = Array("nacllcan".utf8)
    let iv: Array<UInt8> = AES.randomIV(AES.blockSize)
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            let key = try PKCS5.PBKDF2(password: password, salt: salt, iterations: 4096, keyLength: 32, variant: .sha2(.sha224)).calculate()
            let encrypted = try AES(key: key, blockMode: CBC(iv: iv), padding: .pkcs7).encrypt(input)
            let base64String: String = encrypted.toBase64()
            let md5Data = encrypted.md5()
            let md5DataBase64 = md5Data.toBase64()
            print("Encrypted:\(encrypted),\n Base64String:\(base64String)")
            print("md5:\(md5Data),\n md5String:\(md5DataBase64)")
            completion(base64String,md5DataBase64)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

You have to use CryptoSwift to generate these md5 and base64String keys to send in the headers, This will upload the encrypted file to the AWS and to open it or decrypt it you have to use the same base64 key

Hope this will help someone and save hours of time